# Routing system with array - Sending parameter with variable

Tags: php, arrays, regex, model-view-controller, routes

I try to build a routing system with PHP. I have a problem with changeable URLs.

```
private $routes = array(
    "blog" => array("Blog", "GetAll"),
    "/blog\/*/" => array("Blog", "GetOne"),
);

private $query;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->query = filter_var($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
}

public function SendAction()
{
    $route = array();
    if (array_key_exists($this->query, $this->routes)) {
        $route['controller'] = $this->routes[$this->query][0];
        $route['action'] = $this->routes[$this->query][1];
        $route['params'] = $this->routes[$this->query][2];
    } else {
        $route['controller'] = "Error";
        $route['action'] = "Main";
        $route['params'] = array();
    }
    return $route;
}
```

The problem is with the url that contains `abc/my_custom_variable_or/slug`.

I need to get `my_custom_variable_or` and `slug` and put them into `params['fdsaf']` so I can use it in my controller

I find a temp solution with else if, like: `else if (preg_match("/blog\/*/", $this->query))` .... `explode()` etc...

To make my system more flexible, I need to make something in `$routes` array. The routes array will be a different file.

===Sample inputs and the expected results===

URL: blog

```
$route['controller'] = Blog
$route['action'] = GetAll
$route['params'] = array()
```

URL: blog/my-first-post

```
$route['controller'] = Blog
$route['action'] = GetOne
$route['params'] = array('slug' => 'my-first-post')
```

URL: blog/user/martin/page2 (page2 is optional)

```
$route['controller'] = Blog
$route['action'] = GetUserPost
$route['params'] = array('slug' => 'martin')
```

Comment: I edit the question and add sample inputs and expected results

Answer (score 0):

My regex pattern will capture 3 groups.  The first is the leading text -- for all three samples inputs, this is `blog`.  The second group will either be empty or `user` -- this identifies when `GetUserPost` is to be used.  The third group may be empty or contain the `slug` value.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZdeC8/1)

Code ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4a80d981307130d79cd18d1203fa1213538909b)):

```
if(preg_match('/^([^\/]+)\/?((?:user)?)\/?((?:[^\/]+)?)/',$v,$out)){
    $route['controller']=ucfirst($out[1]);
    if($out[2]==''){
        if($out[3]==''){
            $route['action']='GetAll';
            $route['params']=[];
        }else{
            $route['action']='GetOne';
            $route['params']=['slug'=>$out[3]];
        }
    }else{
        $route['action']='GetUserPost';
        $route['params']=['slug'=>$out[3]];
    }
}
```

---

Hard-coded `Blog` version:

```
$inputs=['blog','blog/my-first-post','blog/user/martin/page2'];
foreach($inputs as $v){
    $route=[];
    if(preg_match('/^[^\/]+\/?((?:user)?)\/?((?:[^\/]+)?)/',$v,$out)){
        $route['controller']='Blog';
        if($out[1]==''){
            if($out[2]==''){
                $route['action']='GetAll';
                $route['params']=[];
            }else{
                $route['action']='GetOne';
                $route['params']=['slug'=>$out[2]];
            }
        }else{
            $route['action']='GetUserPost';
            $route['params']=['slug'=>$out[2]];
        }
    }
    var_export($route);
}
```

Output (from either method):

```
array (
  'controller' => 'Blog',
  'action' => 'GetAll',
  'params' => 
  array (
  ),
)array (
  'controller' => 'Blog',
  'action' => 'GetOne',
  'params' => 
  array (
    'slug' => 'my-first-post',
  ),
)array (
  'controller' => 'Blog',
  'action' => 'GetUserPost',
  'params' => 
  array (
    'slug' => 'martin',
  ),
)
```